# Change Column Random Numbers To Serial

Tags: r, dataframe

In a data set, there is a specific column that as random values which repeat at regular interval. I want to replace these  with increasing values as explained below.

**Column_B has random data**

```
Column_A Column_B
  1.5       0
  0.2       1
  0.3       5
  4.5       6
  12.5      7
  1.6       0
  7.8       1
  1.8       5
  6.9       6
  11.0      7
```

**After transformation Column_B should have**

```
Column_A Column_B
  1.5       0
  0.2       1
  0.3       2
  4.5       3
  12.5      4
  1.6       0
  7.8       1
  1.8       2
  6.9       3
  11.0      4
```

Is there a faster way to do this rather than creating a new column and then replacing it with `Column_B`? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know in advance how frequently the pattern repeats?

Comment: @dww - Yes. For the data set I have it's every 64 (as an example I showed above after 5). I don't see it changing at least for what I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recycling to fill the column with a repeating sequence. for example, if you want the sequence to be 64 long before repeating then you can use

```
DF$column_B <- 0:(64 - 1L)
```

More generally, for patterns like your example in which each element within the repeating sequence is distinct, you can find how long the sequence is, using `which`, then do the same thing

```
seq.length = which(dt$B == dt$B[1L])[2L] - 1L
dt$B = 0:(seq.length - 1L)
```

Answer (score 1):

We group by cumulative sum of 'Column_B' where elements are 0 (or where there is decrease in the next element) and get the sequence of roww to assign it to 'Column_B'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Column_B := as.integer(seq_len(.N)-1), cumsum(Column_B==0)]
df1
#    Column_A Column_B
# 1:      1.5        0
# 2:      0.2        1
# 3:      0.3        2
# 4:      4.5        3
# 5:     12.5        4
# 6:      1.6        0
# 7:      7.8        1
# 8:      1.8        2
# 9:      6.9        3
#10:     11.0        4
```

Or find the difference between adjacent elements in 'Column_B', get the cumulative sum based on that to create the `group_by` variable

```
setDT(df1)[, Column_B := as.integer(seq_len(.N)-1), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Column_B)< 0))]
```